# On iOS, the if() statement has different result between release version and debug version

Tags: iphone, ios, pointers, if-statement

I have an app submitted to Apple Store, and it passed. But I found there was a bug will make the app crash. Finally, I found the real problem is a snap of code has the opposite result.

code:

```
CGPoint now;
CGPoint old;
UIView *lastDot;
now = dotView.center;
if(lastDot){
    //release version, will go here. then crashed.
    old = lastDot.center;
}else{
    //debug version, will go here. run ok.
}
```

---

I declare a UIView pointer, and check it with "if statement",

UIView *lastDot;

the debug version consider the lastDot as nil, but the release version think is not null.

can anyone give me any idea? thank you.

Comment: @CodaFi: Huh? `if (lastDot)` is equivalent to `if (lastDot != nil)`

Comment: meadlai, are you sure `lastDot` isn't a `__weak` reference? If it's weak, then it can be nilled out in between the if statement and the subsequent statement.

Comment: @KevinBallard explicit comparisons are the new "Egyptian-curly braces."  Best to let the compiler know what we want before it works it's magic.  And perhaps the variable is being turned to junk before your comparison?  Get po'ing

Comment: @CodaFi: It's not magic. Stop spreading FUD. §6.8.4.1.2 of the ANSI C spec, in regards to if statements: "In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0.". `if (lastDot)` performs `lastDot != 0`. `if (lastDot != nil)` performs `(lastDot != nil) != 0`. They're equivalent statements.

Comment: @CodaFi: Also, using `if (pointerVal)` has a very long history of usage in C. Using an explicit comparison is matter of style, nothing more.

Comment: When running in the debug version (simulator?) have you tried simulating a low memory scenario? That's more likely to occur on a real world device and the results may lead to the crash in production which you don't see in simulation.

Comment: @CodaFi: You're misinterpreting his post. The problem he describes applies explicitly to casting a value to `BOOL`. It's just a subtle integer truncation issue. That has absolutely no bearing whatsoever on how `if` statements work. I already quoted you the relevant section of the ANSI C spec, and if you'll notice there's no truncation issues there.

Comment: @CodFi In the article you linked there's a cast that's causing that issue. There is no cast here.

Comment: @DavidRavetti, I didn't use simulator, I  build it with release option, and run on the hardware iPhone device. and thank you, everyone. It now solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to uninitialized pointer.

Initialize it to nil for avoiding such troubles.

```
UIView *lastDot = nil;
```

I know you already got the answer.

I just want to add some points too:

> **Pointers are just like any other variable: if you don't explicitly set
>   them to a value, the value will be undefined means a random value. If
>   you then accidentally access the variable, very bad things can happen.**
>
> Sometimes people recommend that pointers be assigned to NULL, the
>   universal value meaning "this pointer doesn't point at anything",
>   because a lot of code already checks for NULL pointers. For example,
>   if you call `[nil release]`, it's guaranteed to do nothing. If you
>   passed an uninitialized pointer in who knows what would happen.
>
> It's really just a safeguard against programmer error. If you
>   initialize pointers to a reasonable value, it's less likely that an
>   uninitialized pointer will cause a system crash sometime in the
>   future.
>
> **When you don't initialize a pointer and then try to use it, you have 3
>   problems:**
>
> - It might be pointing at memory you don't have access to, in which case it causes a segmentation fault and crashes your program
> - It might be pointing at real data, and if you don't know what it's pointing to, you're causing unpredictable (and very hard to debug)
>     changes to your data.
> - You have no way of knowing if it's been initialized or not - because how do you tell the difference between a valid address and the address
>     that happened to be there when you declared the pointer?
>
> **Initializing every pointer to `nil` seriously decreases or eliminates
>   those problems:**
>
> - If I try and use it, it will still segfault, but at least I can test if it's NULL and act accordingly - I can know that it WILL segfault,
>     and do something else. If it's a random value, I don't know anything
>     until it crashes.
> - If you initialize it to `nil`, I can't make it point to data unless I explicitly tell it to. So I only modify what I meant to.
> - As implied above, I can tell when I've initialized it and when I haven't, and make a decision.
>
> Obviously it's a matter of style, and it is possible to write an
>   application where variables are only initialized to their intended
>   value, but I feel it is safer and easier to initialize them to `nil`
>   always. Even the best programmers make typos - `nil` makes it easier
>   to know when that's happened.

Reference :

1. [eskimo](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx7.html)
2. [Initializing pointers always necessary](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/129311-initializing-pointers-always-necessary.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't have systematic knowledge on those aspect, that I need to enhance...

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your compiler settings, debug builds usually initialize pointers to some sentinel values like `0xcccccccc`.

```
UIView *lastDot = nil;
```

Should work as expected.

Comment: Good point. I assumed the real code wasn't literally declaring a local variable `lastDot` and then using it, but you're right, use-before-initialization is actually a reasonable cause. That is, as long as he's not using ARC (which initializes all automatic obj-c variables to `nil` for you).

Comment: Thank you, I did not use ARC in the project, and we only provide the debug build version to the test team. It works fine now.